# In Kusto (KQL), how can I call a user-defined function for each row in a table and union the outputs

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Right now, I have a user-defined function `MyFunc` that takes a datetime as input and returns a table with **multiple** columns and a single row representing the state of a system at that time. For example,

```
MyFunc(make_datetime(2023, 3, 12)) => datatable(Time:datetime, A:int, B:int) [
    datetime(2023, 3, 12), 1, 2
]
```

and the next day

```
MyFunc(make_datetime(2023, 3, 13)) => datatable(Time:datetime, A:int, B:int) [
    datetime(2023, 3, 13), 2, 2
]
```

I'd like to call this function at multiple datetimes and union the results into a single dataset. Currently, I have to write

```
MyFunc(make_datetime(2023, 3, 12))
| union MyFunc(make_datetime(2023, 3, 13))
```

which outputs

```
datatable(Time:datetime, A:int, B:int) [
    datetime(2023, 3, 12), 1, 2
    datetime(2023, 3, 13), 2, 2
]
```

However, this is inconvenient as I have to manually specify each datetime I want to query the system at. Instead, I would like to be able to specify a range like

```
let dates = range Timestamp from make_datetime(2023, 3, 12) to now() step 1d;
```

so I can apply `MyFunc` to each value in the range and then union the results.

So far, I've tried using `dates | extend = MyFunc(TimeStamp)` which doesn't work because the function returns multiple columns. I've also been playing around with `mv-apply` with little success.

Comment: Could you pls. add in your question an example with data, with the expected resultset (see here how to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#example) ?

Sounds you are looking for scalar function (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#examples).

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question accordingly. I cannot modify the function so that it becomes a scalar function as it is used by many others. However, maybe I can create a wrapper that takes the single-row output and converts it into a dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I created an UDF and used `UNION` on `range` values and the UDF result to get desired result.

**Sample code**

```
let  myFunc = (datetime1 : datetime )
{
let  tbl = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, A:int, B:int) [
datetime(2023, 3, 12), 1, 2,
datetime(2023, 3, 13), 2, 2
];
tbl
};
let  q =range  Timestamp  from  make_datetime(2023, 3, 14) to  now() step 1d;
q | union  myFunc(toscalar(q))
```

**Result**

[image]